# Get value of System.out.println from main method called via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm calling the main method of a class via reflection. For example:

```
Object o = clasz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
Method method = clasz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
method.invoke(o, new String[1]);
```

The called code looks as:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is a test");
    }
}
```

The reflection works fine and I can see the message in the console.

Is there a way to register something like a binding to the method invocation, for example a PrintWriter or a custom decorated Writer, so I can get the print value as a String?

Comment: There is no point in creating an instance of the class when calling a `static` method. You could just use `clasz.getMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, new String[0]);` instead. But why are you invoking the main method via Reflection instead of just `Test.main(new String[0])`? What problem do you want to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change what `System.out` is bound to using `System.setOut();`. You can then make your own:

```
public class MyTeeingPrinter extends OutputStream {
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final PrintStream original;

    public MyTeeingPrinter(PrintStream original) {
        this.original = original;
    }

    @Override public void write(int b) {
        original.write(b);
        buffer.write(b);
    }

    public String getAndClear() {
        String s = buffer.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        buffer.reset();
        return s;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
MyTeeingPrinter tee = new MyTeeingPrinter();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(tee));
```

and now you can invoke `tee.getAndClear()`.

It's a bit of a slog, because whatever code you are running like this is presumably badly designed - it should have instead taken a `PrintStream` or preferrably an `Appendable` or `Writer`, and would write into this writer. Then a trivial one-liner `main` can be made that just tosses `System.out` into a writer and hands that to this code you're attempting to run for the case where you just want that code to run and write to sysout, and you can make your own (and stop using reflecting to invoke that main method) and hand that to this code you are running in this scenario.

Note that your reflective code 'works' but is bizarre. There is no need to make a new instance; `main` is static. The right way is:

```
Method method = clasz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
method.invoke(null, new String[1]);
```

Comment: This writes to a file, and all other application logs will be printed there too. Is there a way to get only the prints produced by the main method?

Comment: Where does it write to a file?

Comment: @Ventrue this does not write to a file. There is no way to get _just_ what main prints. I explained how the very notion that you want this info suggests this entire stack of software is badly designed; perhaps look there for a pointer as to how to solve the conundrum. If not: Well, when working around badly design APIs, you get into problems, such as 'oh, but this captures everything' - well, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

1. That `main()` method is called in the same process, hence, you can just provide your own stdout implementation/decorator via `java.lang.System.setOut(PrintStream)` before the reflection magic
2. An empty string array would work: `new String[1]` -> `new String[0]`
3. You don't need to create a new object to call the static method. Even though java allows calling static methods via objects, this is a bad style and sometimes might cause problems because of name shadowing. Consider the example below:

```
public class Parent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent child = new Child();
        child.test();
    }

    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("Parent.test()");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("Child.test()");
    }
}
```

It actually calls `Parent.test()` even though it's invoked on a `Child` object

Comment: This writes to a file, and all other application logs will be printed there too. Is there a way to get only the prints produced by the main method?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes because for every call to your own stdout you can print the current stack trace and make conclusions on what code produced the output. No because it's terribly slow and generally bad design.